# Removing unwanted text from Excel

Tags: vba, excel

I currently have a VBA code running in-order to eliminate text from my excel data sheet. The area where I am having a problem is that the line where I have Pear, in the data set, Pear sometimes appears in one cell as Pear and Pineapples. And so when I run this code, it deletes wherever pear shows up. I want the code to only eliminate pear when it is alone.

As for apple and banana, if it appears with another fruit, it is fine if it is deleted, it is only for pear that I need this restriction.

```
Sub DeleteMultipleRows()
        Call DeleteRows(ActiveSheet.Range("A1:A65536"), "Apple")
        Call DeleteRows(ActiveSheet.Range("A1:A65536"), "Banana")
        Call DeleteRows(ActiveSheet.Range("I1:I65536"), "Pear")
End Sub

Sub DeleteRows(ByVal rng As Range, ByVal term As String)
    Dim c As Range
    Do
        Set c = rng.Find(term, LookIn:=xlValues, lookat:=xlPart)
        If Not c Is Nothing Then c.EntireRow.Delete
    Loop While Not c Is Nothing
End Sub
```

Comment: Have you tried `lookat:=xlWhole` instead of `lookat:=xlPart`?

Comment: See what that does is now it works for pear but not for apple and banana @TylerH

Comment: Have you tried `matchcase:=false` or `matchcase:=true` ?

Comment: Could you possibly share how you think the code should be @Jeeped

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can add an optional parameter to your `DeleteRows` sub to give you more control over its behavior:

```
Sub DeleteMultipleRows()
        DeleteRows ActiveSheet.Range("A1:A65536"), "Apple"
        DeleteRows ActiveSheet.Range("A1:A65536"), "Banana"
        DeleteRows ActiveSheet.Range("I1:I65536"), "Pear", False
End Sub

Sub DeleteRows(ByVal rng As Range, ByVal term As String, _
               Optional LookAtPart As Boolean = True)
    Dim c As Range
    Do
        Set c = rng.Find(term, LookIn:=xlValues, _
                         lookat:=IIf(LookAtPart, xlPart, xlWhole))
        If Not c Is Nothing Then c.EntireRow.Delete
    Loop While Not c Is Nothing
End Sub
```

Comment: Set c = rng.Find(term, LookIn:=xlValues, _
                         lookat:=If(LookAtPart, xlPart, xlWhole)


This gives me and error

Comment: @WaleedMalik There are two "I"s in his `IIF()`; make sure you copied it completely rather than typed it manually (I see it is missing from your comment).

Comment: @TylerH so i removed the I initially since I thought that was the error but it still gives me an error

Comment: Edited - was missing the closing `)`